# Missing .gitconfig files after installing Git on new Windows 10 box (also, SourceTree not launching BeyondCompare)

Tags: git, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree, git-config, beyondcompare

I'm setting up my new Windows 10 box, and I'm not sure Git installed correctly. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

First, I downloaded and installed Git (v2.26.2) from here: https://git-scm.com/download/win

I use SourceTree (v3.3.8) with BeyondCompare4 (v4.3.4) as the external diff tool. The problem I ran into is that SourceTree won't launch BeyondCompare. Everything should be configured correctly in SourceTree's options. After some investigation, I found this post: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/external-diff-stopped-working/qaq-p/970290

To summarize, it suggests manually editing the .gitconfig files here: C:\Users\.gitconfig and here: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig

**The problem is that the .gitconfig files do not exist at either location!**

After a bit more searching, I found a suggestion to run, "git clone https://github.com/git/git". I did so at the root C:. But it just created a new C:\git folder with a bunch of stuff in it; but no .gitconfig file here either.

SourceTree is working fine otherwise though. I can push and pull code just fine.

Everything worked just fine on my old Windows 7 box. I had zero issues. Admittedly, I have no idea how I installed everything on that machine originally...

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that Git's home directory defaulted to H:. My computer doesn't have an H:. I ended up adding a system variable to Windows to set my home directory to my default user folder. Then everything just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 4.3.4 should work with SourceTree 3.3.8.

Here's how I setup Beyond Compare to launch as a diff tool in SourceTree on Windows 10:
In SourceTree, open **Tools > Options**.
Go to the **Diff** tab.
Under **External Diff Tool**, select Beyond Compare from the dropdown.

To launch a Diff:
In your workspace, right click on an unstaged file and select **External Diff**. This should launch a diff in Beyond Compare.

If this doesn't work, it might help to try an alternate external diff tool from the **External Diff Tool** dropdown in SourceTree's **Tools > Options** dialog to determine if the problem is Beyond Compare specific or if it's a more general SourceTree problem.

Comment: The problem ended up being that Git's home directory defaulted to H:\. My computer doesn't have an H:\. I ended up adding a system variable to Windows to set my home directory to my default user folder. Then everything just worked.

Comment: @adamjhilton That was the solution for me too. I think this deserves to be posted as an answer.